# Xamarin.android error message while setting up Xamarin.forms solution

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am completely new to Xamarin.forms and going through the Quickstart tutorial from the Xamarin site. I am using a Mac and after creating my solution I started getting the error message with Android. How can I resolve this please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your project properties and make note of android version which
  it's targeted to
- Make sure the same SDK version is downloaded on your machine.
- You need to check SDK Path of respective IDE you're using
- **Visual Studio:** Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android > SDK
- **Xamarin Studio:** Xamarin > Options > Sdk > Android > SDK